# Test Class with non static variable error message

Tags: java, class, methods, static

I am a creating a testMethod() class below to test methods in the Main class. When I executed the program, it gave a compiler error: Java non static variable cannot be referenced from Non Static context.  The project calls for 2 different classes constructed. The first class must consists of 3 methods, in which the third one calls for method 1 and 2. The second class is used to test methods in the main class.

I am new to Java, and I am struggling to figure out what causes this error.

Thanks

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
 char reply;
 int input;

     public void gradeModule(int mark) {
    mark = input;
    if (mark >= 70) {
        System.out.println("Excellent");
    } else if (mark >= 60 && mark <= 69) {
        System.out.println("Good");
    } else if (mark >= 50 && mark <= 59) {
        System.out.println("Satisfactory");
    } else if (mark >= 40 && mark <= 49) {
        System.out.println("Compensatable fail");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Outright fail");
    }

}

 public int getValidModuleMark() {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (input > 100 || input < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid mark between 0 - 100:  ");
        input = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    return input;

}

public void startModuleGrading() {

     System.out.println("*********** Module Grading Program *********");


     do {

         getValidModuleMark();

         gradeModule(input);


         System.out.println("Would you like to continue grading (Y/N)? ");
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         reply = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

         if (reply == 'N' || reply == 'n') {
             System.out.println("Thank you!");
         }


     } while (reply == 'Y' || reply == 'y');


}
```

}

class testMethod {

```
Main test = new Main ();

public static void main(String [] args){

    test.startmoduleGrading();

}
```

}

Comment: Has your class gone over testing before, e.g. JUnit? Can you copy previous examples? The typical answer to this situation is to just build another class and have it run tests against the original class (to test class `A`, make class `B` and have `B.main()` instantiate an object of type `A` and test all its functionality).

Comment: Either by using a test framework (junit, testng) or just a simplified approach by doing a method call and comparing the output with the expected return value (which would be just another implementation of assertEquals)

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER TO ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

Based on what i'm reading here, your teacher probably wants one class like this:

```
class X
{
    public int methodOne(int i)
    {
         return i++;
    }

    public int methodTwo(int i)
    {
         return i--;
    }

    public int methodThree(int i)
    {
         return methodOne(i) + methodTwo(i);
    }
}
```

Then you would have another class for testing:

```
class Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         X test = new X();
         System.out.println(test.methodOne(3));
         System.out.println(test.methodTwo(3));
         System.out.println(test.methodThree(3));
    }
}
```

This shows that you made the class and that the methods work.

**ANSWER TO UPDATED QUESTION:**

In your code, you have declared the `Main test = new Main ();`

outside of your main method, which is indeed a static method. Move the declaration inside of the method and everything should work. Thus, your program should look like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Main test = new Main ();
    test.startmoduleGrading();

}
```

Comment: For me, a test would imply that you have some determined behaviour for these two functions and you would want to test that. A print is imho not enough for a test.

Comment: I agree, but I think in the case of this question he is probably a brand new CS student who hasn't worked with multiple classes before. I just wanted to make a really simple example to show what class interaction can look like.

Comment: The tester class will be more effective (like a JUnit class would need to be) if it didn't just print the results of the function calls, but verified them against the programmer's expected result. `assertEquals(4, test.methodOne(3));`

Comment: Thanks. Except, when I ran it, I got the following error msg: java: non-static  variable cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: @dryre did you declare anything as static in the flow of the program. IF so, then what did you declare as static?

Comment: @DerekPendleton I have edited my post , and shared the codes.

Comment: @dryre I have updated my answer with what should be a solution to your problem.

Comment: @DerekPendleton I tried your alternative method, the following error msg occured:  Error: Main method not found in class Main, please define the main method as:public static void main(String[] args)or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
exit status 1